# Trying to figure out whether the following relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: relations

LEt $R$ be a relation on $\mathbb{N}$ given by $m R n$ iff $m$ and $n$ have the same digit in the tens place. What does it mean to have the same in digit in the tens place?

Comment: @drhab tens place, not tenth place.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I will take away my comment. Excuse: I am Dutch and did not see any difference between tens and tenth. Sorry and thanks for this lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=100a+10b+c$ for $a\in\mathbb N$ and $b,c\in\{0,1,...,9\}$, then $b$ is the digit of $x$ in the tens place. Then you need to check that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, which it is.

---

Another way to write the digit $b$ in the tens place of $x$ is $b=\lfloor x/10\rfloor\pmod{10}$.

Comment: @crash: That approach seems less general to me. Why make it more detailed about the higher places, when we do not need them anyway?

Comment: @crash If $N=1087$ then $N= 100(100)+8(10)+7$, and $100\in \Bbb N$. We only need to be concerned about the 'tens' place.

Comment: @crash: Then $N=1327=100\cdot 13+10\cdot 2+7$ and so on. More generally $1000a+100b+10c+d=100(10a+b)+10c+d$.

Comment: $1327 = 100\times 13+10\times 2+7$, $10293785576 = 100\times 102937855+ 10\times 7+6$, et cetera

Comment: @String Well, it's a *very* weird way of representing base-10 numbers IMO, but I can see what you mean, and only the tens place is being considered anyway. I'll remove my comments.

Comment: @crash: Please do not remove them - it is a valid question, a valid concern IMO.

Comment: @String Sorry. I already removed them. :( I'll briefly express here again what I mentioned so others will see what I commented on -- Usually a base-10 number $N$ is represented as 
$$
N= a_nb^n+a_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2b^2+a_1b+a_0,
$$
where $0\leq a_i<b, i=0,1,\ldots,n$. My quibble had to do with the following: Our own numeral system is an example of a positional numeral system with base $10$. For such a system, after the base $b$ has been selected, basic symbols are adopted for $0,1,2,\ldots,b-1$. Thus, there are $b$ basic symbols, frequently called the digits of the system.

Comment: [cont'd] We then represent the number $N$ (as done above) to base $b$ by the sequence of basic symbols
$$
a_na_{n-1}\ldots a_2a_1a_0.
$$
Thus, a basic symbol in any given numeral represents a multiple of some power of the base, the power depending on the position in which the basic symbol occurs.

Comment: @crash: Nice context and details in those last two comments! I find it relevant, since others may very well think along the same lines.

Comment: @String Thanks. Hopefully now people won't think I'm an idiot haha. In view of our petty misunderstanding, good answer. +1

Comment: I Just show it is an equivalence relation. But just to understand this relation better, I want to compute equivalence classes of some elements. For instance, take in [106], 200 and 30 belong to this equivalence class, correct ?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: The equivalence classes are infinitely huge. You are correct that $200\in[106]$, but not $30\in[106]$ since $3\neq 0$ which are the tens place of $30$ and $106$ respectively.

Comment: how about $0$ ?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: In the number $30$, the digit $0$ sits in the $1$'s place, not the $10$'s.

Comment: I mean, the number $0$ is trivially in this equivalence class, correct?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: OK, I get what you mean. Yes, $0$ belongs to $[106]$, but I do not find that any more trivial than testing whether any other $x\neq 0$ belongs to $[106]$.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but too much for a comment.

In the context of proving that the relation is an equivalence it is irrelevant what is meant by "have the same in digit in the tens place". Relevant is only the existence of a function $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$ that sends $n\in\mathbb N$ to this digit (whatever it is).

Then:$$mRn\iff f(m)=f(n)$$ and this makes it easy to prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation:

- $f(m)=f(m)$ so reflexive.
- $f(m)=f(n)\implies f(n)=f(m)$ so symmetric.
- $f(m)=f(n)\wedge f(n)=f(k)\implies f(m)=f(k)$ so transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Like $\mathbf{1}2$ and $3\mathbf{1}8$, $900\mathbf{7}1$ and $\mathbf{7}0$.

But not $381\mathbf{0}2$ and $381\mathbf{1}2$.